How do I implement training a neural network when generating the data on spot?
I would like to construct a surrogate model of a physics simulation. Thus I am able to generate the data by myself. The data itself is very big, so it makes sense to generate a few data samples (e.g. a batch of 124) and then use it for training immediately instead of generating million of samples as I could not save such data set. In this way I could generate a batch, save it temporarily/send it to my neural network that is waiting for data and then after training on it discard it.
I usually implement my models with pytorch and I am also familiar with the torch.utils.data.DataLoader that can fetch batches into the RAM but it needs the directory structure and file ID's, i.e. a whole dataset needs to be saved somewhere.

First, your statement regarding DataLoader is not exactly correct. The rules of where the data is stored and where it is fetched from will be controlled by the __getitem__ or the __getitems__ in the Dataset object tied to the DataLoader. The easiest solution to your problem would implementing a CustomDataset which would be a subclass of the torch.utils.data.Dataset class. Probably something like this
class CustomDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self, ndatapoints):
    self.len = ndatapoints #the number of points you want to generate
    '''
    declare any other parameters related to your simulation here, just remember to add self. before the, to make them persistent in the class
    '''
  def __len__(self):
    return self.len

  def __getitem(self, id):
    '''
    simulate one datapoint here, maybe use id as a random seed, put the data in a torch.Tensor using something like dataTensor = torch.as_sensor(...)
    '''
    return dataTensor

You might also wanna look into torch.utils.data.IterableDataset. Then declare this and put it into a DataLoader
dataset = CustomDataset(10000)
dataLoader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=124)

You can use the dataLoader like any others you have seen and it will basically generate batch_size number of dataPoints at a time and you can use them as batches for your training/alidation. If your simulation happens on CPU, then you might wanna set the num_workers kwarg in the DataLoader constructor to concurrently generate more than one batch at once.
